# How to capture last part of the git url using shell script?

Tags: bash, git, shell

I am writing a Jenkins pipeline. I am trying to capture last part of the git url without the git extension. For instance: https://github.hhhh.com/aaaaaa-dddd/xxxx-yyyy.git. I want only `xxxx-yyyy` to be returned. Below is my code:

```
String getProjectName() {
    echo "inside getProjectName +++++++"
    # projectName = sh(
    #         script: "git config --get remote.origin.url",
    #         returnStdout: true
    # ).trim()
    def projectName= sh returnStdout:true, script: '''
    #!/bin/bash
    GIT_LOG = $(env -i git config --get remote.origin.url)
    echo $GIT_LOG
    basename -s .git "$GIT_LOG"; '''
    echo "projectName: ${projectName}"
    return projectName
}
```

PS: Please ignore the commented lines of code.

Comment: You could use `awk`?

Comment: @Pritish : If your URL is stored in the variable `GIT_LOG`, you could get it on stdout by `basename $GIT_LOG .git`. Your `basename -s .git $GIT_LOG` would also work (no need to quote the variable here, because by construction it can't contain spaces). In what way is it that your approach does not work?

Comment: @user1934428 Omitting quotes from user-provided values is dangerous. `git config --get remote.origin.url` can be any garbage. That this is a valid URL is just a *convention*; there is nothing that enforces its validity.

Comment: Good to know. I thought that if you have a space in an URL, it **must** always be written as `&20`.

Comment: @user1934428 As I said, that's the *convention*. But nothing enforces that the value of `remote.origin.url` follows that convention.

Comment: Interestingly, [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_urlencode.asp) thinks otherwise. In the paragraph _URL Encoding_, it says _URLs cannot contain spaces_. I then looked up [RFC 1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738), which hopefully is an authoritative source for this matter, and it says under the heading _Unsafe:_ : _The space character is unsafe ... All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL._.

Comment: @user1934428 How does the cited text prevent that the user says `git config remote.origin.url "invalid url"` and then runs the shell script? Spoiler: It cannot; and that's the reason we *always* quote variables containing (unverified) external data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No space before and after `=`:

```
x='https://github.hhhh.com/aaaaaa-dddd/xxxx-yyyy.git'
basename "$x" .git
```

Output:

```
xxxx-yyyy
```

Answer (score 4):

There is basic Bourne shell functionality that achieves that:

```
# strip everything up to the last /
projectName=${GIT_LOG##*/}
# strip trailing .git
projectName=${projectName%.git}
```

This leaves just the requested name in `projectName`.